# Will I have problems because of a harassment warning?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday I played a game where sometimes my enemy in mid lane went to the bottom lane. Every time he did that I used the ping enemy missing. My adc didn't hear it or didn't care and he died this way twice.

He started flaming a bit and I only said I've pinged. I said one more thing in this game for being late to join a fight.

When the game ended I received this message:
[image: Warning message]

It was the first time that I saw that warning.

**Question**

Can I get problems because of that?

Comment: LoL, the most toxic player base of all MMO games.

Comment: @LokiSinclair you never played the original dota...

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW nah banlists fixed that quick

Comment: @turbo banlist was vigilantism

Comment: banlists never worked...

Comment: Actually I find CS:GO a lot worse. Especially because of the voice chat. Having someone wishing you cancer in chat is bad but having a 12 year old boy cursing in voice chat is even worse. If League gets a voice chat however... R.I.P

Comment: have you guys heard of Heroes of Newearth? @LokiSinclair

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This warning shows up if you have been reported **multiple** times and yes you can get problems if you are getting reported in the future.

This is basically the first stage out of three that occur after multiple reports. The three stages are:

1. Warning message (the one you got)
2. Chat/Ranked restriction
3. Temporary ban (up to a month)

Now to prevent innocent people from getting banned or restricted the warning message exists (There are always people who report everyone if they lose and sometimes you're unlucky and have 3 of those in a row). However if you recieve a Chat/Ranked restriction or even a ban you probably are a toxic player (or  you have a really bad day) since it requires multiple reports in a row.

Getting banned is extremely rare but it can happen to the most toxic players in the community, and I'm talking about the constantly flaming and insulting ones.

If you are no [tilter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190507/what-is-the-meaning-of-tilting-or-being-on-tilt) or flamer you shouldn't be too worried, however if you do show your frustration in chat you might want to try not writing anything at all while communicating via pings. Everyone has bad days and gets frustrated sometimes but instead of criticizing someone you should either try to be positive or neutral.

Compliments and a good attitude will also boost the team morale and further increase your chances of winning.

Comment: The official FAQ states alert is sent after only one valid report, not multiple.

Comment: I used to be toxic (last season) However you after 1k chat restrictions I kinda decided to disable my chat completely in the game config. BUT I got reported two weeks ago for saying gg in post chat and got a verbal abuse next day bam chat restriction. I knew that it was probably because I was toxic last season but its still kinda fustrating considering I just said gg. So yes you can get reported and a warning and chat ban, IF you were toxic and IF i guess as Jutschge said if you were reported multiple times in a row

Answer (score 4):

**Why you received that alert :**

> Alerts will be sent to players after they receive a valid report through the post-game reporting system. Keep in mind you may not receive the alert right away, so even if in your previous match you were the picture of positivity, an alert can still pop-up a few games later.

**Is there any serious risk of being banned ?**

> No. The Behavior Alert system is specifically in place to help prevent players from being punished by the Tribunal, so hopefully we'll be able to help you direct your behavior down a more appropriate and friendly path!

*(from [Riot FAQ](https://support.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/201752924-Behavior-Alerts-FAQ))*

So you are probably fine, just make sure you are *not* being toxic.

It just means that at least one player was angry enough to fill a valid report.

Also, GL & HF     :D

Comment: Yeah, the answer to that question is basically a lie - read closely, it means you're not at risk of being banned because you're expected to change your behavior, but if your behavior didn't merit the reports in the first place you clearly _are_ at risk of being banned because there's nothing you can reasonably change and no reason not to expect more reports. They don't even bother to give any assurance that they actually investigate before banning people rather than simply relying on reports, so I assume they _don't_ do this.

Comment: I think they do.

Comment: @Random832, I've played since beta, I'm active on the forums and on reddit, and I have more then 4000 games of all types under my belt. I've never received a warning because I can tell you with a 100% certainty that I've sworn in game exactly once. And have flamed an enemy player exactly twice and never a teammate. If your not toxic you don't end up in the behavior system. Also in all that time I've never run across a ban that the user could **prove** wasn't deserved.

Comment: @ryan What proof given by the user would satisfy you that the ban was undeserved?

Comment: @Erik chat records, which if you happen to ask for on reddit or the forums, a Riot employee by the name RiotLyte is often happy enough to supply. I've seen 50 or 60 plus examples now where someone complained about being banned unfairly, and he came along with the official chat records and it's obvious that the ban was more then deserved.

Comment: It's easier to prove that the ban was deserved than the opposite.

Comment: @ryan OK, that seems very reasonable. I suppose I am just too used to companies that refuse to discuss bans much less provide a record of what led to the ban.

Comment: @Erik, yep that's usually the case I'm familiar with too. So it's refreshing that Riot tries when they can to be transparent about it. In fact the situation I described with RiotLyte has happened so often it has it's own meme in the community. It's said someone complaining about a ban is asking to be "Smited by Lyte" and his chat records.