# Difference between tilted and triggered?

Tags: terminology, overwatch

I'm new to overwatch and from the few times I've heard ppl saying things on open mic I commonly hear the following phrases :

- I'm tilted.
- I'm on tilt
- I'm triggered
- This is triggering

Or some variation of those phrases. Now based off of the link here [What is the meaning of 'Tilting' or 'Being on Tilt'?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190507/what-is-the-meaning-of-tilting-or-being-on-tilt)

I under stand what tilt is. But is it the same as being triggered? Or is there some other meaning of the word triggered in this context?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a gaming specific term.

Comment: @Frank: It might not be a technical gaming term like "FPS", but I think it falls pretty well inside of being a "gaming culture" term.  I might use words like "tilted" and "salty" in conversions that aren't about games when talking with friends who are also gamers, but I would never use it talking to my boss or someone else who isn't a gamer.

Comment: @Frank perhaps this is a misconception but with my online friends in games is the only time I have ever heard (or read) them used. Maybe I'm not all that socially active but I figured the terms are current part of gaming sub-culture and posted my question here. If they are not gaming culture terms. Then what culture do you suppose they fall under?

Comment: This is on-topic as per the meta post, [Are questions about terminology not limited to games on topic?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11358/4797) Voting to reopen.

Comment: I think it would be btr if you removed the overwatch tag since these terms are not solely limited to overwatch but to other games as well.

Comment: I feel that it needs to be said as well, a word "trigger/ing" has a particular meaning that's usually abused in games lately. I would prefer if people started to use it less as it usually used the same way that "a bundle of sticks" is tossed around with toxic intent online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Triggered usually refers to someone getting upset at some behavior or action taken by someone else.  It has a similar meaning to getting "ticked off".

Tilting is unfocused frustration at generally everything because things aren't going your way, which causes you personally to perform worse, which can worsen tilt.

Tilted and triggered are very different.

Comment: OK so as a follow up. Can being tilting be made worse by being triggered while on tilt? Is that grammatically correct?

Comment: "Being tilt*ed*", but yes.

Comment: "Triggered" is usually associated with PTSD.

Comment: @arda outside of this context, possibly yes. Triggers are linked to a variety of unpleasant/undesirable experiences, not necessarily with a formal PTSD label.

Comment: @Ash I never heard the term "triggered" outside that context. TIL I guess :/

Comment: Tilted, more commonly referred to as "salty".

Comment: @Kaizerwolf so your saying salty and tilted are like synomous to each other?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I would argue that "salty" and "tilted" are very different. Tilted refers to a general mindset or attitude of how you're playing - being on tilt means you play worse because small mistakes aggravate you more (even when they really don't matter). Being salty refers more to being a sore loser. Enemy team wins, you start critiquing them: "You only won b/c you're playing cheesy champions" or similar. You can be salty without being on tilt, and you can be on tilt without being salty.

Comment: Of course, as with any "slang" terms (especially those used in gaming), there are no strict definitions, and a lot of this kind of terminology is subjective.

Answer (score 4):

"Triggered" means your stimulated by someone else's behavior etc. and may likely be something that you can relate to. It originates from the term "trauma trigger", a psychological term used to describe a case when an event happens to bring a traumatic event come back into memory.

"Tilt" is actually a poker term for a state of mental or emotional confusion or frustration in which a player adopts a less than optimal strategy, usually resulting in the player becoming over-aggressive. It has since been utilized by the gaming community to relate to a scenario where you lose a lot of games in a row, therefore causing you to go on "tilt" and lose more.

*(Fun fact: The most likely origin of the word "tilt" is as a reference to tilting a pinball machine. The frustration from seeing the ball follow a path towards the gap between the flippers can lead to the player physically tilting the machine in an attempt to guide the ball towards the flippers. However, in doing so, some games will flash the word "TILT" and freeze the flippers, causing the ball to be lost for certain. The metaphor here being over-aggression due to frustration leads to severely detrimental gameplay.)*

Reference: Wikipedia